# 'small children' Vs. 'young children'

Tags: idiomatic-language, style

I've been told in past, that it isn't idiomatic to say 'small children', but instead it should be 'young children. Today, I saw an English native speaker from the UK who said 'my small children'. Is there something wrong with that, or is that's okay?

To my ears, it might be sound like small children in their height, while young is more accurate. I'd like to know what's really going on the spoken English language and considered natural.

Comment: Whomever told you that is wrong. It is common to say "small children" at least in the US. Are you specifically asking about British usage?

Comment: It is perfectly idiomatic to say 'small children'. Did you do any research, such as a Google search for ["small children"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22small+children%22)?

Comment: @FeliniusRex 'whomever'? And 'small children' is idiomatic in British English too.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey am not asking just because. I already saw in past native speakers or multiple results on google which said grammatical mistakes. For example: "She don't" instead of "she doesn't". I am a bit careful with googling.

Comment: I think that the British Medical Journal of 1939 is sufficiently formal.  (Letter, "Evacuation of Small Children"), third Google hit for me.

Comment: It is also common in BE to say "little children" which means the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a native UK English speaker and I can confirm that "small children" is perfectly acceptable as an alternative to "young children", though it is slighly more colloquial.